# Machine Learning in R - confusion matrix of an ensemble

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, confusion-matrix, ensemble-learning

I'm trying to access the overall accuracy (or confusionMatrix) of an across a number of classifiers but can't seem to find how to report this.

Already tried:

```
confusionMatrix(fits_predicts,reference=(mnist_27$test$y))
```

> Error in table(data, reference, dnn = dnn, ...) :    all arguments
>   must have the same length

```
library(caret)
library(dslabs)
set.seed(1)
data("mnist_27")

models <- c("glm", "lda",  "naive_bayes",  "svmLinear", 
            "gamboost",  "gamLoess", "qda", 
            "knn", "kknn", "loclda", "gam",
            "rf", "ranger",  "wsrf", "Rborist", 
            "avNNet", "mlp", "monmlp",
            "adaboost", "gbm",
            "svmRadial", "svmRadialCost", "svmRadialSigma")

fits <- lapply(models, function(model){ 
  print(model)
  train(y ~ ., method = model, data = mnist_27$train)
}) 

names(fits) <- models

fits_predicts <- sapply(fits, function(fits){ predict(fits,mnist_27$test)
  })
```

I'd like to report the confusionMatrix across the different models.

Comment: You don't seem to have an ensemble, just a bunch of models...

Comment: As I see it, the question is incomplete, because it is an ensemble, but it lacks the vote system, the majority vote decides the final model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not training any *ensemble*; you are just training a list of several models, without combining them in any way, which is definitely not an ensemble.

Given that, the error you get is not unexpected, since `confusionMatrix` expects a single prediction (which would be the case if you had an ensemble indeed), and not multiple ones.

Keeping your list for simplicity to only your first 4 models, and changing slightly your `fits_predicts` definition, so that it gives a dataframe, i.e.:

```
models <- c("glm", "lda",  "naive_bayes",  "svmLinear")

fits_predicts <- as.data.frame( sapply(fits, function(fits){ predict(fits,mnist_27$test)
}))

# rest of your code as-is
```

here is how you can get the confusion matrices **for each one of your models**:

```
cm <- lapply(fits_predicts, function(fits_predicts){confusionMatrix(fits_predicts,reference=(mnist_27$test$y))
})
```

which gives

```
> cm
$glm
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  2  7
         2 82 26
         7 24 68

               Accuracy : 0.75           
                 95% CI : (0.684, 0.8084)
    No Information Rate : 0.53           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.266e-10      

                  Kappa : 0.4976         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.8875         

            Sensitivity : 0.7736         
            Specificity : 0.7234         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7593         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7391         
             Prevalence : 0.5300         
         Detection Rate : 0.4100         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5400         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7485         

       'Positive' Class : 2              


$lda
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  2  7
         2 82 26
         7 24 68

               Accuracy : 0.75           
                 95% CI : (0.684, 0.8084)
    No Information Rate : 0.53           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.266e-10      

                  Kappa : 0.4976         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.8875         

            Sensitivity : 0.7736         
            Specificity : 0.7234         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7593         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7391         
             Prevalence : 0.5300         
         Detection Rate : 0.4100         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5400         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7485         

       'Positive' Class : 2              


$naive_bayes
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  2  7
         2 88 23
         7 18 71

               Accuracy : 0.795           
                 95% CI : (0.7323, 0.8487)
    No Information Rate : 0.53            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 5.821e-15       

                  Kappa : 0.5873          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.5322          

            Sensitivity : 0.8302          
            Specificity : 0.7553          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7928          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7978          
             Prevalence : 0.5300          
         Detection Rate : 0.4400          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5550          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7928          

       'Positive' Class : 2               


$svmLinear
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  2  7
         2 81 24
         7 25 70

               Accuracy : 0.755           
                 95% CI : (0.6894, 0.8129)
    No Information Rate : 0.53            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 4.656e-11       

                  Kappa : 0.5085          
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1               

            Sensitivity : 0.7642          
            Specificity : 0.7447          
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7714          
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7368          
             Prevalence : 0.5300          
         Detection Rate : 0.4050          
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5250          
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7544          

       'Positive' Class : 2
```

And you can also access the individual confusion matrices per model, e.g. for `lda`:

```
> cm['lda']
$lda
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  2  7
         2 82 26
         7 24 68

               Accuracy : 0.75           
                 95% CI : (0.684, 0.8084)
    No Information Rate : 0.53           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.266e-10      

                  Kappa : 0.4976         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 0.8875         

            Sensitivity : 0.7736         
            Specificity : 0.7234         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.7593         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.7391         
             Prevalence : 0.5300         
         Detection Rate : 0.4100         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5400         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.7485         

       'Positive' Class : 2
```